# Having a hard time using chrome.tabs.sendMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background

I'am sure this topic has already been discussed somewhere on this website but as a newbie I can't really figure this out on my own..

I'am trying to code a very "simple" chrome extension so that when a user clicks on a certain button, it triggers an alert.

As far as I understood, the click needs to be listened then the background has to communicate with my content in order to display the alert.

Here is my code :

Manifest

```
{
  "name": "Test alert",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is a test",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js" : ["content.js"]
  }]
}
```

Background

```
document.getElementById("edit-payment").addEventListener("click", function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "saySomething"}); });
```

Content

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.action === 'saySomething') {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

I'am having trouble when it comes to message passing. Can anyone enlighten me pls ?
Thank you for your time !

I've been trying to use chrome.tabs but something is wrong.

Comment: The callback function inside the event listener is expecting `tabs`. Isn't this supposed to be an event? Your `tabs[0]` will probably be undefined. The [sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage) expects a numerical tab ID

Comment: 1) Where is that `edit-payment` button? The background script doesn't have it. 2) Your listener is missing `()=>chrome.tabs.query({},` before `function(tabs)` and another ) at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background script doesn't have access to the document and
`document.getElementById("edit-payment")` won't work. It is the content script that has access to it!

> The service worker (background script):
>
> The extension service worker handles and listens for browser events. There are many types of events, such as navigating to a new page, removing a bookmark, or closing a tab. It can use all the Chrome APIs, but it cannot interact directly with the content of web pages; that’s the job of content scripts.

See: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/extensions-101/#extension-files

Comment: Wrong: 1) MV2 background script has DOM, 2) content scripts can't use chrome.tabs.